# Ubuntu Studio low latency kernel

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-studio

I've installed Ubuntu Studio 14.04 on my computer and I thought that the installation would also give me a low latency kernel too, but when I click 'extra audio production application' it says that I can install the complete low latency kernel. My question is, is part of the kernel already installed or do I need to download it and then install it? Sorry if this may seem a noobish question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer your question exactly, but I'll try.
According to this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudioPreparation
"ubuntu" users can opt to install lowlatency kernel manually OR install the ubuntustudio package.  (Wich is not to install "ubuntu studio" flavour, wich is your case)

I've been using Ubuntu studio since release 9.04 when it came with a realtime kernel.  I used 10.10 for many years and I had to manually install rt-kernel for it, and realtime was excellent for multitrack recording with audio.  Later on I used 12.04 live, wich came with a normal kernel, but some delay was noticeable for multitrack recording.
This year I choosed to upgrade to 16.04 LTS, but I preferred to install Ubuntu 16.04 and install "ubuntu studio" as a package over "ubuntu" (because ubuntu 16.04 is a 5 year support release, and ubuntu studio 16.04 is a only 3 years support release)
Installing ubuntu studio as a package did not install lowlatency kernel (and I found your question looking for information on that).

If you wanna check if you have a lowlatency kernel I suggest you to run synaptic (package manager) and search there for lowlatency to see if it's installed.  (I don't know the command for the kernel to inform it's version, sorry)  You can install Synaptic from "Ubuntu Software" application, and I recommend it for installing specific packages.  (Ubuntu used to came with Synaptic instead of "ubuntu software").

**If lowlatency is not installed, you can install it from Synaptic, or run these two commands:**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

(this will update the repositories with latest packages available for your 16.04 release)
AND:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency linux-headers-lowlatency
```

You should install those 2 packages together.
I think that in grub bootloader you'll have options to choose the kernel for each boot.  (lowlatency or normal)

Well, that's all I can tell about this.

Comment: Run "uname -r" in a terminal, it will return your current kernel version.  I remembered it! hehe